# Button in RecyclerView cannot be clicked or selected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have put a button inside a `RecyclerView` to move it to the next activity but when i clicked the button it did nothing including not moving it to the next activity.

I have tried putting the button outside the `RecyclerView`, but when the `RecyclerView` comes, the button has gone. And i have tried to modify all codes regarding the `RecyclerView` but without success.

This is the Activity for showing it

```
package com.example.rsolveapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RsolverMatch extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference database;
    private RecyclerView rvView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Description> daftarBarang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rsolvermatch);

        rvView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
        rvView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        database.child("description").addValueEventListener(new 
     ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                daftarBarang = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : 
    dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Description description = 
    noteDataSnapshot.getValue(Description.class);
                    description.setKey(noteDataSnapshot.getKey());

                    daftarBarang.add(description);
                }


                adapter = new AdapterDescRecyclerView(daftarBarang, 
    RsolverMatch.this);
                rvView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                System.out.println(databaseError.getDetails() + " " + 
    databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public static Intent getActIntent(Activity activity){
        return new Intent(activity, RsolverMatch.class);
    }
}
```

This is the first .xml layout for the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/background1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
        android:id="@+id/cv_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background_material_light"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2.5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/descText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Description : "
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_namabarang"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/dayText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Working Day :"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_day"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/daysHour"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Start Working Hour : "
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_shour"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_smin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/dayeHour"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="End Working Hour : "
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_ehour"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=":"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tv_emin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takeJob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Take Job"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the second .xml layout for the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The expected result is the button can be clicked and it moves to the next activity.
Here is the error messages in the logcat :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.rsolveapp, PID: 13737
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rsolveapp/com.example.rsolveapp.RsolverMatch}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2914)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.example.rsolveapp.RsolverMatch.onCreate(RsolverMatch.java:56)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7131)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Here is my AdapterRecyclerView Activity

```
public class AdapterDescRecyclerView extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDescRecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Description> daftarBarang;
private Context context;

public AdapterDescRecyclerView(ArrayList<Description> barangs, Context ctx){

    daftarBarang = barangs;
    context = ctx;
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvday;
    TextView tvshour;
    TextView tvsmin;
    TextView tvehour;
    TextView tvemin;
    CardView cvMain;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_namabarang);
        tvday = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_day);
        tvshour = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_shour);
        tvsmin = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_smin);
        tvehour = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_ehour);
        tvemin = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_emin);
        cvMain = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cv_main);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = 
  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_job, 
  parent, false);
    // mengeset ukuran view, margin, padding, dan parameter layout lainnya
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final String name = daftarBarang.get(position).getDescription();
    final String day = daftarBarang.get(position).getDay();
    final String shour = daftarBarang.get(position).getsHour();
    final String smin = daftarBarang.get(position).getsMin();
    final String ehour = daftarBarang.get(position).geteHour();
    final String emin = daftarBarang.get(position).geteMin();


    holder.tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


        }
    });
    holder.tvTitle.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            return true;
        }
    });
    holder.tvTitle.setText(name);
    holder.tvday.setText(day);
    holder.tvshour.setText(shour);
    holder.tvsmin.setText(smin);
    holder.tvehour.setText(ehour);
    holder.tvemin.setText(emin);


}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return daftarBarang.size();
}
}
```

This is my Rsolvermatch Activity that already impelements the onclicklistener but resulting in an error

```
package com.example.rsolveapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;




public class RsolverMatch extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {


private DatabaseReference database;
private RecyclerView rvView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ArrayList<Description> daftarBarang;
Button takeJob;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.rsolvermatch);


    rvView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
    rvView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    takeJob.setOnClickListener(this);
    takeJob = findViewById(R.id.takeJob);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



    database.child("description").addValueEventListener(new 
    ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            daftarBarang = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
                {

                Description description = 
                noteDataSnapshot.getValue(Description.class);
                description.setKey(noteDataSnapshot.getKey());


                daftarBarang.add(description);
            }

            adapter = new AdapterDescRecyclerView(daftarBarang, 
            RsolverMatch.this);
            rvView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            System.out.println(databaseError.getDetails() + " " + 
            databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == takeJob) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RsolverMatch.this, Chatting.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

        public static Intent getActIntent (Activity activity){
            return new Intent(activity, RsolverMatch.class);
        }
    }
```

Comment: show code of your adapter 'AdapterDescRecyclerView'

Comment: where is the click listener for the button, add the code for adapter as well.

Comment: You kinda forgot to add the relevant code that contains `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: @Makarand adapter added to my code summary

Comment: @EpicPandaForce already adeed the onclicklistener but i got an error from it so i deleted it again

Comment: added the debugging onclicklistener that shows the error instead of working on rsolvermatch Activity

Answer (score 2):

You should put ***setOnClickListener*** for your *button* inside the Adapter's **onBindViewHolder** function. And use the position as **viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();** when you click on button of any item in recyclerview.Also pass whatever arguments you need for doing **startActivity();** in the adapter's Constructor.

Comment: I was trying to reference a button from a different layout but i don't know how to do it, i already tried putting onClickListener from my rsolvermatch activity referencing to the itemjob.xml. So after i got the error from that i removed the onclick listener.

Comment: i added the Rsolvermatch activity which included the onclicklistener that resulting an error i added before

Comment: @BryanRatin You can set click listener inside you view holder class also. If you want to set click listener for full item than set it on view comes to your viewHolder class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it right.

Now just add a button in layout `item_job.xml` and do

```
   holder.myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (context, NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("argumentKey", argumentValue);       
    context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

in `onBindViewHolder`